# what are the benefits of using toRef or toRefs to destructure props in vue3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

can I use a props without using `toRefs`, what problems can occur?
What is the cost of using `toRef`?

```js
const props = defineProps(['background', 'blueBackground']);
const { background } = toRefs(props);
```

Comment: The benefit of toRefs is that you have a separate ref at hand that can be passed somewhere. It's a mistake to use it on props because this results in writable ref, while props are supposed to be readonly